# Showing the induced short exact sequence is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, homological-algebra

Suppose that we have a Long Exact sequence

$$...\rightarrow A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{b} C \xrightarrow{c} D \xrightarrow{d} E \xrightarrow{e} F \rightarrow...$$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$
Show then that the following induced short sequence is exact:

$0 \rightarrow\coker(a) \xrightarrow{\tilde{b}} C \xrightarrow{\tilde{c}} \im(c) \rightarrow 0$

*Proof*:

Let $\bar{x} \in B/\im(a) = \coker(a)$ and suppose $\tilde{b}(\bar{x})=0$

Then $b(x)=0$

So $x \in \ker(b) = \im(a)$

so $\bar{x} \in \im(a)$

$\rightarrow \bar{x} = 0$

Thus $\tilde{b}$ is injective and thus the S.E.S. is exact at $\coker(a)$

I will now show exactness at $C$.

let $x \in C$ and $\bar{c}(x)=0$

This implies that $c(x)=0$

so $x \in \ker(c) = \im(b)$

so $b(y)=x$ for some $y \in B$.

Thus $\bar{b}(\bar{y})=\bar{x}$

And so $\ker(\bar{c}) \subset \im(\bar{b})$

Now Let $x \in C$ and suppose that $\bar{b}(\bar{y})=x$

then $x \in \im(\bar{b})$

so $x \in  \im(b) = \ker(c)$

thus $\bar{x} \in \ker(c)$

Thus this S.E.S. is exact at C.

Is this correct so far?

Comment: What difficulty do you have showing exactness at $C$ and $im(c)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tilde c : C \to \text{im} C$ be the restriction of $c : C \to D$ to its image. Let $\tilde b : \text{coker} a \to C$ be the induced map on the quotient. That is, if $q : B \to \text{coker} a$ is the quotient map then $\tilde b$ satisfies $b = \tilde b \circ q$

It is clear from the definition of $\tilde c$ that $\tilde c$ is surjective.

Note that $\text{coker} a = B / \text{im}a = B / \text{ker}b$ by exactness. So $\tilde b$ is injective.

Lastly if $x \in \ker \tilde c$ then $x \in \ker c$ and by exactness $x \in \text{im} b$. From the definition above it is easy to see that $\text{im} b = \text{im} \tilde b$, so we are done.

Comment: I agree, the result is quite obvious. However, I'm trying to get my hands dirty on the technical aspects of these type of proofs and want to make sure that my arguments are logically sound.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Alright, if that's the case I'll try and make my post a little more rigorous.

Comment: You mean $ker(\bar{b}) = \frac{ker(b)}{im(a)} = \frac{ker(b)}{ker(b)}$?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Yes I did. Edited now